# NHibernate Cascade not setting foreign key

Tags: c#, nhibernate

As the title states both the parent and child are being inserted into database but not being linked.

Mapping Request

```
  <class name="Request" table="Requests">
<id name="RequestId">
  <generator class="native" />
</id>
<many-to-one name="BulkReport" class="BulkReport" column="BulkId" cascade="none" lazy="proxy" />
<property name="RunNumber" />
<property name="MobileNumber" />
<property name="Message" />
<property name="RequestedOn" />
<property name="Closed" />

<many-to-one name="Communication" class="Communication" column="CommId" cascade="save-update" lazy="proxy" />
<many-to-one name="Outcome" class="Outcome" column="OutcomeId" cascade="none" lazy="proxy" />
<many-to-one name="Discount" class="Discount" column="Discount" not-found="ignore" cascade="save-update" lazy="proxy" />
</class>
```

Mapping Discount

```
  <class name="Discount" table="Discounts" discriminator-value="BASE">
<id name="DiscountId">
  <generator class="native" />
</id>

<discriminator column="DiscountType" not-null="true" />

<property name="MobileNumber" />
<property name="CustomerName" />
<property name="AddedOn" />
<property name="Status" />
<property name="Pending" />
<many-to-one name="Product" class="DiscountProduct" column="DiscountProduct" cascade="none" lazy="proxy" />
<many-to-one name="AddedBy" class="User" cascade="none" lazy="proxy" />

<subclass name="StaffDiscount" discriminator-value="STAFF">
  <many-to-one name="Employee" class="Employee" column="EmployeeNumber" cascade="none" lazy="proxy" not-null="false" />
</subclass>
</class>
```

SQL From Test

```
NHibernate: INSERT INTO Discounts (MobileNumber, CustomerName, AddedOn, Status,          Pending, DiscountProduct, AddedBy, DiscountType) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'BASE');@p0 = 700000000, @p1 = 'Test', @p2 = 25/06/2013 14:38:43, @p3 = True, @p4 = False, @p5 = 1, @p6 = 'Test'
NHibernate: select @@identity
NHibernate: INSERT INTO Requests (BulkId, RunNumber, MobileNumber, Message, RequestedOn, Closed, CommId, OutcomeId, Discount) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);@p0 = 1, @p1 = 100, @p2 = 700000000, @p3 = 'Test Request', @p4 = 25/06/2013 14:38:43, @p5 = True, @p6 = NULL, @p7 = 1, @p8 = 0
NHibernate: select @@identity
```

Any idea why this is happening? got a complete block on this?

edit: Requested information

Discount Class

```
    public class Discount
{
    public virtual int DiscountId { get; set; }
    public virtual double MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime AddedOn { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Status { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Pending { get; set; }

    public virtual DiscountProduct Product { get; set; }
    public virtual User AddedBy { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "0" + MobileNumber + ", " + CustomerName.Trim();
    }
}
```

Request Class

```
    public class Request
{
    public virtual int RequestId { get; set; }
    public virtual BulkReport BulkReport { get; set; }
    public virtual int RunNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual double MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string Message { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime RequestedOn { get; set; }
    public virtual Outcome Outcome { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Closed { get; set; }
    public virtual Communication Communication { get; set; }
    public virtual Discount Discount { get; set; }
}
```

Test I Ran

```
        [Test]
    public void Can_add_new_request_with_discount()
    {
        ISession session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();

        BulkReport report = session.Get<BulkReport>(1);
        Outcome outcome = session.Get<Outcome>(1);
        User user = session.Get<User>("Test");
        DiscountProduct discountProduct = session.Get<DiscountProduct>(1);


        Request request = new Request()
        {
            Message = "Test Request",
            BulkReport = report,
            Closed = true,
            MobileNumber = 07000000000,
            RequestedOn = DateTime.Now,
            RunNumber = 100,
            Outcome = outcome
        };

        Discount discount = new Discount
            {
                AddedBy = user,
                AddedOn = DateTime.Now,
                CustomerName = "Test",
                MobileNumber = 07000000000,
                Pending = false,
                Status = true,
                Product = discountProduct
            };

        request.Discount = discount;

        session.Save(request);

        var fromDbRequest = session.Get<Request>(request.RequestId);
        var fromDbDiscount = session.Get<Discount>(discount.DiscountId);

        Assert.IsNotNull(fromDbRequest);
        Assert.IsNotNull(fromDbDiscount);
        Assert.AreEqual(request.MobileNumber, fromDbRequest.MobileNumber);
        Assert.AreEqual(discount.MobileNumber, fromDbDiscount.MobileNumber);

        session.Close();
    }
```

Comment: not in the schema I am using? what version was it introduced?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that one's not available on `many-to-one`. Do you have a Discount.Requests property? If so, what type of collection is it? The reference from Discount -> Request is not mapped above.

Comment: Discount is not mapped to request only need it one way from Request to Discount. There will only ever be one Request per Discount but not all Discounts are requested (some manually entered into system)

Comment: When you are saving (and expecting the FK to carry over), are you saving the Discount or the Request? Also, are you calling `session.Save` or `.Merge`? Every test I run with similar mappings works fine. It also might help if you just post minimal versions of your Discount and Request objects.

Comment: I have updated the question with the Discount and Request Class and also the test i ran

Comment: Can you please *reduce* the question to the minimal required information? It takes time to read all this and time is money ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That test looks wrong. You really should use transactions (and call `transaction.Commit()`). Alternatively, call `session.Flush()`. If you do either you will most likely get a update statement that sets the `Discount` in the `Request`.

Not related to your problem, but you should open a new session for getting your `fromDb` objects, otherwise no DB request is made because they are already in the session's first level cache

Comment: Cant believe I didn't see that all other tests have been made as you said. Was too focused on the database and mapping and not the code. Thanks